# What is the difference between MockMvc and WebTestClient?

Tags: spring, mockmvc

When I tried to test at Spring 4.x, I used MockMvc web client, 
but I am reading and trying new features of Spring 5.x.

I think, WebTestClient and MockMvc are same or very similar.

What is the difference between MockMvc and WebTestClient ?

I am waiting for your answer.
Thank you

Comment: From the documentation, WebTestClient is used to test WebFlux application while MockMVC is used to normal MVC web application

Answer (score 25):

### Similarities

- Both provide a [fluent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)-style syntax for testing web services.
- Both can or do operate in a simulated environment that bypasses the use of HTTP.

### Major Differences

- WebTestClient can also be used to test real web services using HTTP.

  - Specify `@SpringBootTest` instead of `@WebFluxTest`.
- WebTestClient only works if you are using [Netty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netty_(software)) for your local server.

  - This feels like an artificial limitation for the test environment.
  - It is likely due to the non-blocking nature of the underlying [`WebClient`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html).
- WebTestClient can test [Streaming Responses](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#webtestclient-stream)

### Resources

- [Benefits of having HTTP endpoints return Flux/Mono instances instead of DTOs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40964700/86967)
- [Unable to use reactive WebClient without spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9690)
- [WebTestClient documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/reactive/server/WebTestClient.html)
- [Spring Boot Data Rest don't support reactive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44871147/86967) -- limitations of Netty

Comment: It seems like there is some ability to use both `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-webflux` in the same app, but trying to do so may be more trouble than it's worth.  Basically, these are two separate and mutually-exclusive stacks.

Comment: As far as I know, using mvc and webflux in the same application is not supported.

Comment: and also I know ,also you can use webtestclient with tomcat

Comment: `spring-boot-starter-web` is compatible with `WebClient` and `WebTestClient`. In fact, I believe it's recommended now since the use of `RestTemplate` is currently discouraged.